# The texture behind Maps and Safari on iPad: can I use it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

In the iPad Maps app, when you lift the page curl, you see a sort of cross-hatched table-top texture underneath.

This look the same (or at least very similar) to the texture you see in the Safari app when you scroll beyond the end of a page.

Is this texture available for me to use in my app, or is it just something that Apple have used in a few of their apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless `[UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor]` is what is rendering it, then no you wont be able to use it.

It will be a private resource.

Comment: Yep, that's the one I was looking for. Thanks!